# Post Params Not Sent to Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, url-parameters, ngresource

I have a simple `$resource` factory.

```
.factory('Order', order)

order.$inject = ['$resource', "ApiEndpoint", "UserRecord"];

function order($resource, ApiEndpoint, UserRecord) {
  return $resource(ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders.json', {}, {
    create: {method: 'POST', url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders.json'}
  });
}
```

Here is the code I'm executing.

```
var params = {product_id: 32342, variant_id: 536341};

Order.create(params, function( resp ) {
  console.log("success");
});
```

When I run `create` the params are not going through. No params are passing. Why is this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: None. No errors at all. Well besides the one from the server that states no params were sent.

Comment: Does the server respond at all? What appears in the network tab? What's the response?

Comment: The response is a 200. The issue is that the server doesn't receive the params.

Comment: Apologizes. It doesn't receive any of the params. It's as if no params were sent.

Comment: When you say params... do you mean in the url or the POST body?

Comment: POST body. This is a post request so I'm not expecting the params to be within the url.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realized I'm missing a second argument, `POST-DATA`.

```
Order.create(params, {}, function( resp ) {
  console.log("success");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters:

```
HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])
```

So you could try:

```
var params = {product_id: 32342, variant_id: 536341};

Order.create({},params, function( resp ) {
  console.log("success");
});
```

The first parameter is used to fill in the parameters of the url (e.g `/foo/:id` would  require `{id: 324}` as the first parameter)

**Update:**

Got the order of parameters incorrect:

```
var params = {product_id: 32342, variant_id: 536341};

Order.create(params,{}, function( resp ) {
  console.log("success");
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I attempted this but the same result is produced. The params are still not going through.

Comment: I just fixed this. You were close. Just had to swap out the first two arguments.